# Can connect to a socket on my local network but not on separate ones (python sockets)

Tags: python, sockets

I've been trying to make a program that would allow me to remote into my computer. It works perfectly when both computers are connected to the same network, and I am able to access a sort of command line that I have coded.

I am very inexperienced with networks and I'm not entirely sure what sort of information is needed.

This is the code I used:

Server:

```
import sys
import socket

def create_socket():
    try:
        global host
        global port
        global s
        host = ""
        port = 9999
        s = socket.socket()

    except socket.error as msg:
        print("SocketCreationError: " +str(msg))

def bind_socket():
    try:
        global host
        global port
        global s

        print("binding the port " + str(port)+"...")

        s.bind((host,port))
        s.listen(5)

        
    except socket.error as msg:
        print("SocketBindingError: " + str(msg))
        print("retrying...")
        bind_socket()

def socket_accept():
    conn,address = s.accept()
    print("Connection established. \nIP:"+address[0]+"\nPort:"+str(address[1]))
    print(str(conn.recv(1024), "utf-8"), end="")
    send_command(conn)
    conn.close()

#allows user to send command to client computer
def send_command(conn):
    while True:
        try:
            cmd = input(">")
            if cmd == 'exit':
                conn.close()
                s.close()
                sys.exit()
            if len(str.encode(cmd)) > 0:
                conn.send(str.encode(cmd))
                clientResponse = str(conn.recv(1024),"utf-8")
                print(clientResponse, end="")
        except Exception:
            print("Something went wrong...")

def main():
    create_socket()
    bind_socket()
    socket_accept()

main()
```

Client:

```
import socket
import os
import subprocess

#connect to socket and send cwd
s = socket.socket()
host = 'myIP'
port = 9999

s.connect((host, port))
s.send(str.encode(os.getcwd()))

#allows form of command line on host pc
while True:
    try:
        data = s.recv(1024)
        outputStr = ""
        
        if data.decode("utf-8") == 'dir':
            dirList = os.listdir(os.getcwd())
            
            for i in dirList:
                print(i)
                outputStr = outputStr + i + "\n"
                
        elif data[:2].decode("utf-8") == 'cd':
            dirTo = data[3:].decode("utf-8")
            print(data[3:].decode("utf-8"))
            os.chdir(os.getcwd() + "\\" + dirTo)
        elif len(data) > 0:
            cmd = subprocess.Popen(data.decode("utf-8"), shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
            outputByte = cmd.stdout.read() + cmd.stderr.read()
            outputStr = str(outputByte, "utf-8")
            print(outputStr)
            
        cwd = os.getcwd()
        s.send(str.encode(outputStr +"\n"+cwd))

#handle something going wrong and just allows to continue
    except Exception:
        cwd = os.getcwd()
        s.send(str.encode("Something went wrong...\n"+ cwd))
```

I am using ipv4 addresses. I think it may have something to do with port forwarding on the server side, but again I am not sure?

Thank you for any answers in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't connect to your computer using a remote network because of port forwarding. If you dont know what that is, I recommend taking a look at the Wikipedia article on it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding
There are many different methods to perform Port Forwarding, the simplest of which is the UPnP/IGD (look it up), but if you're just interested in being able to Access your computer remotely, you could just use an SSH (Secure Shell Connection) to do just this (I think it Works on remote networks as well). If you're using Linux this should be pretty easy to set up, just look up how to do it. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. I thought it could be something to do with port forwarding, but wasn't sure. I will have a look into it!